# AIX NIM Master replicate / sync fails to an Alternate Master

Tags: networking, aix, rsh

I am getting a error when I try to replicate / sync my NIM database and resources to an Alternate NIM Master newly created in my environment:

```
error replicating resources: unable to /usr/lpp/bos.sysmgt/nim/methods/c_rsh <my_server_hostname>
```

I already have the APAR IZ67043 installed on my system. Is there any workaround for this situation?

smitty fastpath used:

```
# smitty nim_mac_op_sync_hdr
```

command executed:

```
# nim -Fo sync -a replicate=yes <nim_alt_master_hostname>
```

My environment info:

Power 780 (P7+)
oslevel: 6100-07-081339

Comment: Can you manually rsh from the NIM master to the NIM alt master?

Comment: Both nim servers are in the same subnet, without firewalls?